# GSON name of object

Tags: java, gson

My class is Salary

```
public salary(Integer min, Integer max){
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}
```

When I put

```
salary s = new salay(10,20);

Gson gson = new Gson();

String json = gson.toJson(s);
```

I have result

```
{"min" : 10, "max" : 20}
```

How to get

```
{"salary" : {"min" : 10, "max" : 20}}
```

Comment: your question statement is too short to help understand problem statement and is very "general".

Answer (score 0):

To receive the output that you want, you'll have to store it within a `Map<String, salary>`:

```
Map<String, salary> salaries = new HashMap<>();

salaries.put("salary", new salary(10, 20));

String s = new Gson().toJson(salaries);
```

However, I **highly recommend** that you rename `salary` to `Salary`, as it's proper conventions.